# SQL procedure, stored in Oracle, that runs weekly

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

how can I create a PL / SQL procedure, stored in Oracle, that runs weekly? The procedure, dumps the data from one table to another. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a job that will run your stored procedure scheduled to run weekly.

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
   job_name           =>  'myJob',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'myStoredProcedure',
   start_date         =>  SYSTIMESTAMP,
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=WEEKLY',
   enabled            =>  TRUE);
end;
/
```

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_linux_oracle_dbms_scheduler_create_job.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#ADMIN12063

Answer (score 1):

Oracle includes a comprehensive scheduler for this,
you should see here ;) 
https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g